# Android force quitting

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I'm running this code and the emulator is posting a force quit. Does anyone know what could be wrong?

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

ImageView IV = new ImageView(this);
IV.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.celtics);
IV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.addView(IV);
        tl.addView(tr);
```

Comment: Please provide the stack trace. Stack trace is the information about the exception thrown by your app. It helps to understand and solve the problem.

Comment: Where is this code being run? I had this issue when I put the findViewById() before I called the setContentView()

Comment: It looks like you are adding the tablerow before adding the table layout.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I actually found a way to get around this by doing this dynamically. I deleted the xml file and created the table in Java